# setInterval call function and the html style no change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style>
        .a {
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: #666;
        }

</style>

<body>
    <div class="a">

    </div>

    <script>
        function first() {

            setInterval( a, 1000);
        }

        function a() {
            document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].style.transform = 'rotate(50deg)';
            document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', first);
    </script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/TyTyT/frmawt85/

I found the transform style  stop at 90deg, not change anymore.

What I imagine is that DIV tag will swing between 50deg and 90deg.

How to do that?

Comment: The two statements are executed immediately so you see the final result of 90 degree rotation. There are many ways to achieve what you are looking for, for example css keyframes

Answer (score 1):

It's actually rotating. You need to update the `rotate` value on time. You can try this-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .a {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            /* border: 1px solid red; */
            background-color: red;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="a">

    </div>

    <script>
     var rotate = 0;
        function first() {
            let interval;
            // Don't forget to clear the interval
     if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
            interval = setInterval( a, 1000);
            
        }

        function a() {
         if (rotate > 360) rotate = 0;
         rotate += 50;
            document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].style.transform = `rotate(${rotate}deg)`;
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', first);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is will be circle, how to swing between certain degree

Comment: What do you mean by swing? Any illustration?

Comment: First, to 120deg and then back to 60deg, to 120deg and back to 60deg,  not alway be clockwise

Comment: You mean rotate in a circular path?

Comment: Like pendulum clock

Comment: I think you can do it by using css @keyframe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210250/discussion-between-sajeeb-ahamed-and-ttt).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this solution. I think you are trying to revert back the value and start the loop again like a pendulum if that's the case then i hope this solution will help.

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 20px !important;
}
.a {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .a {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            /* border: 1px solid red; */
            background-color: red;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="a">

    </div>

    <script>
     let rotate = 60;
        function first() {
            let interval;
            // Don't forget to clear the interval
           if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
            interval = setInterval( a, 1000);
            
        }

        function a() {
            if(rotate === 60) rotate += 60;
            else rotate -= 60; 
            console.log(rotate);
            document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].style.transform = `rotate(${rotate}deg)`;
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', first);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling both CSS changes together in one function (a) and that function is fired every one second. So it happens, but very fast after each other.

What you can do in this very simple case is something like this:

```
function first() {

    const degs = ['rotate(50deg)', 'rotate(90deg)'];

    setInterval(() => {
        document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].style.transform = degs[0];
        degs.reverse();
    }, 1000);
}

window.addEventListener('load', first);
```

This works, but ... I would use CSS animations in here. It would be something like this will give also nice touch of smoothnes:

```
<style>
    .a {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        /* border: 1px solid red; */
        background-color: #666;

        animation: exampleAnimation 2s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes exampleAnimation {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(50deg);
        }
        50% {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate(50deg);
        }
    }
</style>
```

You can read more about CSS animations here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: Right, so both cases has solution. For JS, assign that interval into constant. Eg const abc = setInterval etc.. Then, when your event happens, simply call clearInterval(abc). In CSS approach, extract animation into separate class, add it to div.a. When you event happens, remove that class from div.a.

Comment: Sorry, i did't notice js you write. But you say fire together, i have ever put wait()(it's a function wait second and run next code) between that , i still see DIV inonly one state.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bztrduh7/ 
Have a look on this one. Its with the JS code from the answer. From there, you can add the interval into constant, etc